# C++ code showing Line 25: Char 5: error: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]

Tags: c++

Here  is my code:   why does it show compile error??: **non void function does not return a value in all control paths: **

```
vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {     

        unordered_map<int,int> m;
        vector<int> v;
        for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
            if(m.count(nums[i])!=0 and nums[i]==target/2){
                v.push_back(m[nums[i]]);
                v.push_back(i);
                return v;
            }
            else if(m.count(nums[i])==0){
                m[nums[i]]=i;
   
            }            
        }
        for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
            if(m.count(target-nums[i])!=0){
                v.push_back(i);                
                v.push_back(m[target-nums[i]]);
                return v;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If `nums` is empty, how many times do the `for` loops run? Is that a sufficient number of iterations to reach the if cases that do return a value?

Answer (score 2):

> why does it show compile error??:

Because of combination of these facts

- The compiler has been asked to treat warnings as errors.
- The compiler has been asked to warn when a function has a control path that doesn't return a value (although not mentioned in the message, throwing a value and possibly calling a non-returning function may also be considered acceptable).
- As the diagnostic message states, the function does have a control path where a value isn't returned. Consider a case where the vector is empty.

P.S. If function ends without return (or throw), then the behaviour of the program will be undefined. Thus, the warning is a very useful one and you should consider yourself lucky that the compiler noticed the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Your function should return a vector in every possible condition. Currently your code is returning the vector based on conditions. These conditions may be **true** or **false**. In case of false, your function will not return anything and result in compilation error.


**Update**: You need to make your function return a vector in every condition as suggested in comments.

```
vector<int> twoSum(vector<int> &nums, int target)
{

    unordered_map<int, int> m;
    vector<int> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
    {
        if (m.count(nums[i]) != 0 and nums[i] == target / 2)
        {
            v.push_back(m[nums[i]]);
            v.push_back(i);
            return v;
        }
        else if (m.count(nums[i]) == 0)
        {
            m[nums[i]] = i;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
    {
        if (m.count(target - nums[i]) != 0)
        {
            v.push_back(i);
            v.push_back(m[target - nums[i]]);
            return v;
        }
    }
    return v;      // This line to be added
}
```

Comment: I agree. My statement was question specific. I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

It is complaining because within the first for loop, if block returns v but else if block does not return anything.

Comment: Nope, it's not about the `else if`, you don't need to return from every branch. You just need to make sure that function never ends without returning something.